# Reformulate a fractional expression in sympy using a ratio of symbols

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
a,b,c = symbols("a b c")
f = (a*b + c) / (a*b)
```

How to express `f` as a function of the ratio "b/c"?

This is what I want to achieve

```
f = (a*(b/c) + 1) / (a*(b/c))
```

I tried `factor(f, 1/c)`, `factor(f, c)` in the attempt to divide with `c` later, dividing by `c`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally use symbol-trickery to get an expression to look like this since you are asking for the expression to be in a very non-standard form for SymPy:

```
>>> factor(f.subs(b,u*c)).subs(u, Symbol('b/c'))
(a*b/c + 1)/(a*b/c)
```

If you don't create a 'b/c' symbol (i.e. `subs(u, b/c)`), SymPy will give you this:

```
c*(a*b/c + 1)/(a*b)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am working with expressions from fluid dynamics, so I need to express stuff with ratios (non-dimensional numbers) often.